# Xubuntu 20.04 freezes

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu

Xubuntu 20.04 randomly freezes. May I ask, what could be the cause? Thank you

Here is the output of `inxi -F`

```
System:
  Host: r-ESPRIMO-Mobile-X9525 Kernel: 5.4.0-52-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: FUJITSU SIEMENS product: ESPRIMO Mobile X9525 v: 1.0 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: FUJITSU SIEMENS model: Z118M3A v: 20 
  serial: <superuser/root required> BIOS: Phoenix 
  v: Z118D3FR.102 - R058 - 3D13 date: 09/03/2008 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 26.8 Wh condition: 55.4/77.0 Wh (72%) 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core2 Duo P8400 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  Speed: 798 MHz min/max: 800/2267 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 798 2: 798 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA G98M [GeForce 9200M GS] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  resolution: 1680x1050~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: NV98 v: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 82801I HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-52-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel 82567LM Gigabit Network driver: e1000e 
  IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: 00:1e:33:0b:94:2f 
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter 
  driver: ath5k 
  IF: wlp8s0 state: up mac: 00:15:af:1e:e2:d9 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 6.57 GiB (1.4%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WDS500G2B0A-00SM50 
  size: 465.76 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 455.29 GiB used: 6.37 GiB (1.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1 
  ID-2: /boot size: 703.5 MiB used: 201.6 MiB (28.7%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/sda5 
  ID-3: swap-1 size: 980.0 MiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 53.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nouveau temp: 26 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 186 Uptime: 20m Memory: 3.78 GiB used: 1.11 GiB (29.4%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```